# No encuentro el error, la aplicacion no abre

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Nos pidieron que hagamos una aplicacion para guardar contactos o algo así, sin base de datos, que funcione con vectores y todo dentro de una activity (haciendo los objetos visibles e invisibles).
La listView tiene que mostrar el nombre de la persona, y los botones de guardado, crear una nueva nota, mostrar lista, y recorrer el vector tienen que estar en la toolbar. Para guardar la nota en una determinada posicion, hay dos botones, uno que aumenta y otro que disminuye el valor de mi int j.
La verdad se me hace muy poco práctico desde muchos puntos de vista, pero me solicitaron que lo haga así, y bueno, es lo que toca. 
El problema que estoy teniendo es que la aplicación no inicia, y estoy segura de que es un error en el código o en el razonamiento, pero no logro darme cuenta.
Dudo mucho de que esté bien hecho el adaptador de la lista, pero no tengo idea de cómo se hace. 
Cualquiera ayuda es más que bienvenida.

Esto es lo que aparece en el logcat:

> 11-27 01:07:35.654 30060-30060/com.ort.valentina.yamecanse E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                Process: com.ort.valentina.yamecanse, PID: 30060
>                                                                                java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.ort.valentina.yamecanse/com.ort.valentina.yamecanse.Principal}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead.
>                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
>                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2787)
>                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
>                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1504)
>                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6247)
>                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:872)
>                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:762)
>                                                                                 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead.
>                                                                                    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setSupportActionBar(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:207)
>                                                                                    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setSupportActionBar(AppCompatActivity.java:130)
>                                                                                    at com.ort.valentina.yamecanse.Principal.onCreate(Principal.java:50)
>                                                                                    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6754)
>                                                                                    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
>                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
>                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2787) 
>                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
>                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1504) 
>                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
>                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6247) 
>                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:872) 
>                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:762)

Dejo acá los códigos:

.java

```
public class Principal extends AppCompatActivity
{

public int j;

public EditText etxtNombre,  etxtEdad, etxtDni;
public TextView txtNombre, txtEdad, txtDni;
public String Nombre, Edad, Dni;
public ListView lista;
public ArrayAdapter<String> adaptador;
public Toolbar toolbar;
public Contacto[] contactos = new Contacto[20];
public String [] nombres = new String[20];

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_principal);

    etxtNombre = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etxtNombre);
    etxtEdad = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etxtEdad);
    etxtDni = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etxtDni);

    txtNombre = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtNombre);
    txtEdad = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtEdad);
    txtDni = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtDni);

    lista = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lista);
    adaptador = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.elemento_lista, R.id.titulo, nombres);
    lista.setAdapter(adaptador);

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    etxtNombre.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    etxtEdad.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    etxtDni.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    txtNombre.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    txtEdad.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    txtDni.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    lista.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    for(int i = 0; i<20; i++)
    {
        contactos[i] = new Contacto("","","");
        nombres[i] = contactos[i].getNombre();
    }

    contactos[0].setNombre("Alejandro Caropreso");              contactos[0].setEdad("17");      contactos[0].setDni("42.000.000");
    contactos[1].setNombre("Tadeo Bottos");                     contactos[1].setEdad("17");      contactos[1].setDni("42.000.001");
    contactos[2].setNombre("Joaquin Dubroff");                  contactos[2].setEdad("18");      contactos[2].setDni("42.000.002");
    contactos[3].setNombre("Dylan Erdei");                      contactos[3].setEdad("17");      contactos[3].setDni("42.000.003");
    contactos[4].setNombre("Bruno Feldman");                    contactos[4].setEdad("17");      contactos[4].setDni("42.000.004");
    contactos[5].setNombre("Sabrina Garcia");                   contactos[5].setEdad("18");      contactos[5].setDni("42.000.005");
    contactos[6].setNombre("Lucas Goldberg");                   contactos[6].setEdad("17");      contactos[6].setDni("42.000.006");
    contactos[7].setNombre("Jonathan Grojsman");                contactos[7].setEdad("18");      contactos[7].setDni("42.000.007");
    contactos[8].setNombre("Tomas Kviatek");                    contactos[8].setEdad("17");      contactos[8].setDni("42.000.008");
    contactos[9].setNombre("Matías Levy");                      contactos[9].setEdad("18");      contactos[9].setDni("42.000.009");

    lista.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
    {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id)
        {
            etxtNombre.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            etxtEdad.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            etxtDni.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            txtNombre.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            txtEdad.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            txtDni.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            lista.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_principal, menu);
    return true;
}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    switch (item.getItemId())
    {
        case R.id.vectorMenos:

            if (j>=1)
            {
                j = j-1;
                txtNombre.setText(contactos[j].getNombre());
                txtEdad.setText(contactos[j].getEdad());
                txtDni.setText(contactos[j].getDni());
            }

            return true;

        case R.id.vectorMas:

            if (j<=18)
            {
                j = j+1;
                txtNombre.setText(contactos[j].getNombre());
                txtEdad.setText(contactos[j].getEdad());
                txtDni.setText(contactos[j].getDni());
            }

        case R.id.crear_nota:

            etxtNombre.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            etxtEdad.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            etxtDni.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            txtNombre.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            txtEdad.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            txtDni.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            lista.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            return true;

        case R.id.lista:

            etxtNombre.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            etxtEdad.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            etxtDni.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            txtNombre.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            txtEdad.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            txtDni.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            lista.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            return true;

        case R.id.guardar:

            Nombre = etxtNombre.getText().toString();
            contactos[j].setNombre(Nombre);
            txtNombre.setText(Nombre);

            Edad = etxtEdad.getText().toString();
            contactos[j].setEdad(Edad);
            txtEdad.setText(Edad);

            Dni = etxtDni.getText().toString();
            contactos[j].setDni(Dni);
            txtDni.setText(Dni);

            return true;


        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

}

.xml

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lista"
    android:layout_width="180dp"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etxtNombre"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:text="Nombre"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="37dp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etxtEdad"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:text="Edad"
    android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/etxtNombre"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/etxtNombre" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etxtDni"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:text="DNI"
    android:layout_below="@+id/etxtEdad"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/etxtEdad"
    android:layout_marginTop="14dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/guardar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Guardar"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/lista"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtNombre"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/lista"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="29dp"
    android:text="Nombre"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtEdad"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txtNombre"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="21dp"
    android:text="Edad"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtDni"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="27dp"
    android:text="DNI"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txtEdad"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/lista" />
```

Clase contacto:

```
    public class Contacto
{
    String nombre;
    String edad;
    String dni;

Contacto (String nombree, String edadd, String dnii)
{
    this.nombre = nombree;
    this.edad = edadd;
    this.dni = dnii;
}

public void setNombre (String nombre) {this.nombre = nombre;}
public void setEdad (String edad) {this.edad = edad;}
public void setDni(String dni) {this.dni = dni;}

public String getNombre() {return nombre;}
public String getEdad() {return edad;}
public String getDni() {return dni;}
```

}

Comment: Pueds poner el logcat para ver el error

Comment: Ese es el log de gradle, en android studio abajo hay una opcion de Logcat, ahi puedes ver todo lo que pasa en tu app, saldran letras rojas al momento de que tu app se cuelga, trata de copiar todo eso y actualiza tu pregunta con esos datos para poder ayudarte

Comment: Gracias, ahi lo actualice. Todo lo que sale en el logcat esta en rojo

Comment: solución agregada :), si te funciona márcala como resulta

Answer (score 2):

Ok, el error es que estás poniendo un `ActionBar` en tu layout, pero tu activity actualmente tiene un theme con `ActionBar` incluido, por lo que debes quitarlo de tu theme para que no afecte.

**SOLUCION 1**

La solución es ,modifica el theme de tu `Activity` en tu archivo `style.xml`, quítale el actionBar así :

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

La clave es  `<item name="windowActionBar">false</item>`

**SOLUCION 2**

Otra solución podría ser que el `theme` de tu `Activity` extienda de un theme sin `ActionBar`

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
     ...
</style>
```

Ojo que estoy asumiendo que el `theme` de tu `Activity` se llama "AppTheme".
Tu `Activity` en el `AndroidManifest.xml` quedaría algo así:

```
 <activity
        android:name=".Principal"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```